# What is the registry "title index" parameter?

Tags: winapi, registry

What is the registry [`TitleIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566425.aspx) parameter used for? When is it nonzero?

Comment: What `TitleIndex` parameter are you referring to? Your question is too vague, you need to provide more details.

Comment: @Remy: Did you click on the link? There's only one parameter named `TitleIndex`... I'm not sure what's vague about it.

Comment: The link hadn't been posted yet when I made that comment.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: ... uhm, pardon? When was it posted then?

Comment: there is no link provided in your original Question, which was posted at `2011-09-10 02:48:52Z`. My first comment was posted at `2011-09-10 03:57:22Z`. The link was posted in an Answer by Arash at `2011-09-10 11:51:18Z` - 8 hours after my comment.

Comment: @Remy: Are you *sure* there is no link in my original question? I can certainly see one.

Comment: I was before. I could see the word formatted, but it was not clickable as a link. Now it is. Odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood:

```
TitleIndex = Might specify the position in the sequential order of subkeys.
```

[see this link](http://www.koders.com/c/fidC5333E53A7DEC0CF906FA2E795403110B329174F.aspx)

Comment: Interesting... it's obviously speculation but better than nothing, thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

It's a reserved parameter. You should set it to 0.

Comment: not really. It's reserved. In situations where it has an effect, it must be zero.

Answer (score 0):

The *TitleIndex* parameter (for the *ZwCreateKey* and *ZwSetValueKey* routines) doesn't affect registry keys and values as of Windows NT 3.5. In Windows NT 3.1, the value of this parameter is written to the *Title index* field in the low-level structure (stored in memory and on a disk) of the registry key (when the *ZwCreateKey* routine has been called) or the registry value (when the *ZwSetValueKey* routine has been called); however, the value of the *Title index* field isn't used for anything in Windows NT 3.1, and the *Title index* field became deprecated in Windows NT 3.5.

I guess that Microsoft did plan to include localized aliases for key name strings and value name strings, and the *Title index* field was used to store an index of such a localized alias in an external database (although localized aliases were never supported in public versions of Windows NT).

For sure, the *TitleIndex* parameter can't *specify the position in the sequential order of subkeys* (as mentioned in another answer), because subkeys of a registry key are always stored in the sorted order (sorted by the name string).